# Why doesn't scroll bar work in jface dialog

Tags: java, user-interface, swt, scrollview, jface

I'm trying to add a button, text boxes and a label dynamically whenever I hit the add button. I want to achieve this behavior in 2 more composites but on the same dialog. I'm using a scrolled composite so whenever I hit the add button a new label, text boxes, and button are created accordingly.

The problem is whenever they come to end of dialog, the scrolled composite is not appearing to extend the dialog. What is the best way to do this?

### composite_1

1 [        ] [        ] buttonDelete

### buttonAdd

### composite_2

1 [        ] [        ] buttonDelete

### buttonAdd

---

1 [        ] [        ] buttonDelete

### buttonAdd

---

### okButton CancelButton

```
 public class DynamicDialog extends Dialog {
        private Text text;
    private Text text_1;
        private Composite composite;

    /**
     * Create the dialog.
     * @param parentShell
     */
    public DynamicDialog(Shell parentShell) {
        super(parentShell);
    }

    /**
     * Create contents of the dialog.
     * @param parent
     */
    @Override
    protected Control createDialogArea(Composite parent) {
        Composite container = (Composite) super.createDialogArea(parent);
        container.setLayout(new FillLayout(SWT.HORIZONTAL));

        ScrolledComposite scrolledComposite = new ScrolledComposite(container, SWT.BORDER | SWT.H_SCROLL | SWT.V_SCROLL);
        scrolledComposite.setExpandHorizontal(true);
        scrolledComposite.setExpandVertical(true);

        composite = new Composite(scrolledComposite, SWT.NONE);
        composite.setLayout(new FormLayout());
        //scrolledComposite.setContent(composite);
        ScrolledComposite scrolledComposite1 = new ScrolledComposite(composite, SWT.BORDER | SWT.H_SCROLL | SWT.V_SCROLL);
        scrolledComposite1.setExpandHorizontal(true);
        scrolledComposite1.setExpandVertical(true);



        final Composite composite_1 = new Composite(scrolledComposite1, SWT.NONE);
        composite_1.setLayout(new GridLayout(4, false));
        FormData fd_composite_1 = new FormData();
        fd_composite_1.top = new FormAttachment(0, 10);
        fd_composite_1.left = new FormAttachment(0, 10);
        fd_composite_1.bottom = new FormAttachment(0, 85);
        fd_composite_1.right = new FormAttachment(0, 430);
        composite_1.setLayoutData(fd_composite_1);

        Label label = new Label(composite_1, SWT.NONE);
        label.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.RIGHT, SWT.CENTER, false, false, 1, 1));
        label.setText("1");

        text_1 = new Text(composite_1, SWT.BORDER);
        text_1.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.CENTER, true, false, 1, 1));

        text = new Text(composite_1, SWT.BORDER);
        text.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.CENTER, true, false, 1, 1));

        Button btnDelete = new Button(composite_1, SWT.NONE);
        btnDelete.setText("delete");

        final Composite composite_2 = new Composite(composite, SWT.NONE);
        composite_2.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, false));
        FormData fd_composite_2 = new FormData();
        fd_composite_2.bottom = new FormAttachment(composite_1, 41, SWT.BOTTOM);
        fd_composite_2.top = new FormAttachment(composite_1, 6);
        fd_composite_2.right = new FormAttachment(100, -10);
        fd_composite_2.left = new FormAttachment(100, -74);
        composite_2.setLayoutData(fd_composite_2);
        new Label(composite_2, SWT.NONE);

        Button btnAdd = new Button(composite_2, SWT.NONE);
        btnAdd.setText("ADD");
        scrolledComposite.setContent(composite);
        scrolledComposite.setMinSize(composite.computeSize(SWT.DEFAULT, SWT.DEFAULT));
        scrolledComposite1.setContent(composite_1);
        scrolledComposite1.setMinSize(composite_1.computeSize(SWT.DEFAULT, SWT.DEFAULT));

        btnAdd.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
                Label label2 = new Label(composite_1, SWT.NONE);
                label2.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.RIGHT, SWT.CENTER, false, false, 1, 1));
                label2.setText("1");

                Text text_12 = new Text(composite_1, SWT.BORDER);
                text_12.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.CENTER, true, false, 1, 1));

                Text text13 = new Text(composite_1, SWT.BORDER);
                text13.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.CENTER, true, false, 1, 1));

                Button btnDelete = new Button(composite_1, SWT.NONE);
                btnDelete.setText("delete");

                Point p0 = composite_1.getSize();
                composite_1.setSize(p0.x+10, p0.y+10);
                composite_1.setSize(p0);
                composite_1.layout();
                Point p = composite.getSize();
                composite.setSize(p.x+10, p.y+10);
                composite.setSize(p);
                composite.layout();



            }
        });


        return container;
    }

    /**
     * Create contents of the button bar.
     * @param parent
     */
    @Override
    protected void createButtonsForButtonBar(Composite parent) {
        createButton(parent, IDialogConstants.OK_ID, IDialogConstants.OK_LABEL,
                true);
        createButton(parent, IDialogConstants.CANCEL_ID,
                IDialogConstants.CANCEL_LABEL, false);
    }

    /**
     * Return the initial size of the dialog.
     */
    @Override
    protected Point getInitialSize() {
        return new Point(450, 300);
    }

public static void main(String[] args){

    Shell shell =  new Shell(new Display());
    shell.setLayout(new FillLayout());
    DynamicDialog dd = new DynamicDialog(shell);
    dd.open();

}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this applies to your case, but i had trouble making my scrollpane fill the available space. It would either just take up the entire preferred size of the internal components (no scrollbar and larger than the container) or shrink to minimum size.

to fix it i had to set LayoutData:

```
GridData scrollPaneData = new GridData(GridData.FILL_BOTH);
scrolledComposite.setLayoutData(scrollPaneData);
```